# Django URL matching

Tags: python, regex, django, url

Can anyone see why this wouldn't be working? I'm fairly new to Django so any help would be much appreciated.

Actual URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/2010/may/12/my-second-blog-post/

urls.py:

```
(r'(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$', 'object_detail', dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),
```

Answer (score 12):

```
r'(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>\w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 
'object_detail', 
dict(info_dict, slug_field='slug',template_name='blog/detail.html')),
```

You seem to have forgotten the backslashes.

Comment: shouldn't ?P<day>w{1,2} be ?P<day>d{1,2} too?

Comment: @stevejalim could be, \w matches digits too though. Not sure what the author wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying this in an app context or in the project url routing?

You may need to start your regular expression with a ^.

```
(r'^foo/$', 'foo'),
```